# 'Transposing' controls in rows and columns in a WPF Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid

I have a wrappanel that acts as a container for a group of controls defined as

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition  />
      <RowDefinition   />
      <RowDefinition   />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0">test1</Label>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
  </Grid>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition  />
      <RowDefinition   />
      <RowDefinition   />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0">test1</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="60"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" MinWidth="60"></TextBox>
  </Grid>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition  />
      <RowDefinition   />
      <RowDefinition   />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0">test1</Label>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
  </Grid>           
</WrapPanel>
```

So basically it wraps multiple grids that have 3 rows each, and every cell in the grid has a control.
I want the user to have the ability to 'transpose' this layout so that the wrappanel now has a vertical orientation and the grid is now a 3 column grid. So if done manually the xaml would look like

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition  />
      <ColumnDefinition  />
      <ColumnDefinition  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0">test1</Label>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
  </Grid>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition  />
      <ColumnDefinition  />
      <ColumnDefinition  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0">test1</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="60"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="60"></TextBox>
  </Grid>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition  />
      <ColumnDefinition  />
      <ColumnDefinition  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0">test1</Label>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
  </Grid>           
</WrapPanel>
```

1. Whats the best way to achieve this?
2. Is there any way to do this and avoid codebehind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your grid always contain 3 rows and 3 columns.  When you are using "rows", you would need to add `Grid.ColumnSpan="3"` (in order to keep this looking the same), and when transposed, use `RowSpan`.

In order to do the transposition, handling this in code is most likely the simplest option.  By calling `Grid.GetRow`/`SetRow`/etc on your items, you could easily do the transposition.

To avoid putting this into the code behind, you could make an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) which worked on the grid itself.  This would allow you to have the property bind to a boolean or enum in your ViewModel, and perform the transposition at runtime based on business logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you can swap out the Grids for StackPanels

```
    <WrapPanel x:Name="Wrap"
               Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="{Binding Orientation, ElementName=Wrap, Converter={StaticResource InverseOrientationConverter}}">
            <Label>test1</Label>
            <ComboBox MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
            <ComboBox MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="{Binding Orientation, ElementName=Wrap, Converter={StaticResource InverseOrientationConverter}}">
            <Label>test1</Label>
            <TextBox MinWidth="60"></TextBox>
            <TextBox MinWidth="60"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="{Binding Orientation, ElementName=Wrap, Converter={StaticResource InverseOrientationConverter}}">
            <Label>test1</Label>
            <ComboBox MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
            <ComboBox MinWidth="60"></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </WrapPanel>
```

Then you can make use of this converter

```
public class InverseOrientationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is Orientation))
            throw new ApplicationException();

        Orientation orientation = (Orientation)value;

        if (orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            return Orientation.Vertical;

        return Orientation.Horizontal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I did that, I would have to set the width and height of individual controls explicitly or the column arrangement of the controls would not be uniform.